# Problemas símbolos importados Intouch Wonderware Aveva

Tags: descarga

Al importar un proyecto de Intouch a otro ordenador (de máquina física a virtual), a la hora de cargar los símbolos que creé en el proyecto original siempre me carga el mismo símbolo, un motor de barco. Da igual qué símbolo intente utilizar, e incluso al editar se sustituye el símbolo por este motor. Ocurre lo mismo con las ventanas que contienen dichos símbolos, y no ocurre solo con los importados, sino con los que vienen predefinidos.

Este error no ocurre en la previsualización del árbol de Industrial Graphics, pues los símbolos aparecen tal y como se hicieron en el proyecto original, pero en el momento de verlo, cargarlo o editarlo se sustituyen.

Por dar más datos, estoy en una licencia de prueba, trabajando en una máquina virtual, mientras que el proyecto original tenía el mismo tipo de licencia, pero en una máquina en físico.

He buscado el error pero no he encontrado información referente a ésto. ¿Alguien puede arrojar algo de luz a este error? Muchas gracias.